# How to join more than two tables on the basis of two parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have three tables `#temp`, `tbProducts` and `tbVendor`

```
tbVendor(States, AgentId, Products)

tbProduct(ProductId, ProductName)

#temp(ProductName)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
tbVendor
-------------------------------- ----------- --------------------
States                           AgentId     Products
-------------------------------- ----------- --------------------
Alabama,New York                 1           T.V, Desktops
New Jersy, Florida               2           Cellphones, Laptops
New York, San Fransico           1           Cellphones, Desktop
New Jersy, San Fransico          1           A.C, Heaters

tbProduct
----------- -------------
ProductId   ProductName
----------- -------------
1           T.V
2           Laptops
3           Desktop
4           Cellphones
5           A.C
6           Heaters

#temp
---------------
ProductName
---------------
T.V
Laptops
Desktop
Cellphones
A.C
Heaters
```

Now I have perform join operation on them in order to fetch `ProductId` and `ProductName`
Assigned `tbVendor` on the basis `Agent Id` and `States` fields.

For E.g I have fetch all the `Products` with their `Names` and `Ids` in `New york` with `AgentId = 1` the output should be like

```
ProductId   ProductName
----------- -------------
1           T.V
3           Desktop
4           Cellphones
```

Note that `#Temp` contains all the products assigned to `AgentId = 1`. Somehow I managed to fetch all the products assigned to `AgentId = 1` and them in `#temp` tables. Now I am not able manage to fetch the output like i.e only the products assigned to `New York` The expected output is like below

```
ProductId   ProductName
----------- -------------
1           T.V
3           Desktop
4           Cellphones
```

I have tried below lines of code bit it doesnot work

```
Select * from tbProduct L
JOIN #Temp TL  ON L.ProductName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = TL.ProductName
JOIN tbVendor Li ON Li.AgentId = @AgentId and Li.States like @States;
```

Note that `@States` contains `New York` and `@AgentId` contains `1`.

Comment: Can't you redesign database shema? Currently you have comma separated lists for states and products - these make any joins very difficult (you have to use string manipulation) and ineffective.

Comment: I know that this comma has created a lot of troubles... But I have not not designed this schema... If I will do like this I have to re-work the years work which were done by other devolepers. it will take ages to complete the whole project... Please help me

Comment: the structure of tbVendor is violating First NF and it needs normalization. you're storing a comma delimited list in a column and this has many disadvantages. for instance, you won't be able to store a list longer than what fits in the column.Edit: Ok, now I see..

Comment: Can you also include an example of the expected output in the question?

Comment: Check the above question... I have marked the expected output

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you created an [SQLFiddle](http://SQLFiddle.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        AgentId,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(States, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS States,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(Products, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS Products
    FROM @tbVendor
)
,FinalList AS (
SELECT 
    AgentId,
    RTRIM(LTRIM (sTable.sColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS States,
    RTRIM(LTRIM (PTable.PColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS Products
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY States.nodes('//r') AS sTable(sColumn) 
CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('//r') AS PTable(PColumn) 
)
SELECT DISTINCT F.Products AS ProductName
       ,T.ProductId AS ProductId       
FROM FinalList F
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ProductId FROM @tbProduct TP WHERE TP.ProductName = F.Products) AS T
WHERE F.States = 'New York'
AND F.AgentId = 1
ORDER BY T.ProductId ASC
```

UPDATE: To deal with special character LIKE `&` REPLACE it WITH `&amp;` as:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        AgentId,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(States, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS States,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Products,'&','&amp;'), ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS Products
    FROM @tbVendor
)
,FinalList AS (
SELECT 
    AgentId,
    RTRIM(LTRIM (sTable.sColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS States,
    RTRIM(LTRIM (PTable.PColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS Products
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY States.nodes('//r') AS sTable(sColumn) 
CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('//r') AS PTable(PColumn) 
)
SELECT DISTINCT F.Products AS ProductName
       ,T.ProductId AS ProductId       
FROM FinalList F
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ProductId FROM @tbProduct TP WHERE TP.ProductName = F.Products) AS T
WHERE F.States = 'New York'
AND F.AgentId = 1
ORDER BY T.ProductId ASC
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SVXKFH57654)

Comment: Great Efforts...It's working fine but there are some product saved as Beauty & Skin Care and it's throwing XML parsing: line 1, character 100, illegal name character error message for such products

Comment: you will have to replace & with &amp, like wise for other special characters also you will have to replace first ..

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir... I really appreciate that your answer is Excellent Solution

Comment: What about this '-' character I am sorry i forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
DECLARE @state varchar(25) = 'New York',
@agentId int = 1

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Products 
        FROM tbVendor tv 
        WHERE tv.AgentId = @agentId AND tv.States Like  '%' +@state + '%'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS products
INTO #tmp

;with tmp(product, products) as (
select  LTRIM(LEFT(products, CHARINDEX(', ',products+', ')-1)),
    STUFF(products, 1, CHARINDEX(', ',products+', '), '')
from #tmp
union all
select  LTRIM(LEFT(products, CHARINDEX(', ',products+', ')-1)),
    STUFF(products, 1, CHARINDEX(', ',products+', '), '')
from tmp
where products > ''
)
SELECT tp.*
FROM tbProduct tp
INNER JOIN tmp t ON t.product = tp.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the CSV into rows

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   
    -- Split States
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(0))) RNO, 
    AgentId,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'STATE'    
    FROM  
    (
         -- Use 3 REPLACE for  '|', ';', ','
         SELECT AgentId,
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([STATE], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data         
         FROM #tbVendor

    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)   
SELECT C1.AGENTID,C1.[STATE],TAB.Products,P.ProductID     
FROM CTE C1
JOIN
(   
    -- Split Products
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(0))) RNO, AgentId,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Products' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- Use 3 REPLACE for  '|', ';', ','
         SELECT AgentId,         
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Products, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data      
         FROM #tbVendor

    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)TAB
ON C1.RNO=TAB.RNO AND C1.AGENTID=TAB.AGENTID
-- Get Product Id
JOIN #tbProduct P
ON TAB.Products=P.ProductName
WHERE ...your conditions...
```

Now you will get all `states` with `ProductId`, `ProductName` and `AgentId`

[image]

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edccd/3)**